# Find Number of combinations possible

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are two letters "X" and "Y".A String of length N needs to be formed using those two letters How many number of combinations that can be possible where N should start with "Y" and no two or more consecutive "X" will be there?

Consider N=7,

I approached the solution in the following manner:

Solution=No:of combinations that start with letter "Y" -[No:of combinations containing two consecutive X(n-1 possibilities) +No:of Combinations containing 3 consecutive X(n-1 possibilities)+.....].

=2^(N-1)-[(N-2)(N-1)/2];

the problem is with the part I'm subtracting.where I'm missing the elements which contains two consecutive "X" and total of 3 X in the String.Similarly 2 consecutive and total of 4 X. I want to find a generic formula for finding no of Strings that are possible where no 'R' or more consecutive "X" will occur.

Please help me to find the solution for this.

Comment: Let $a_n$ be the number of "good" strings of length $n$. Argue that $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n$.

Comment: "How many number of combinations that can be possible" is a very awkward way of phrasing it.

Comment: Consider counting the $n$-letter strings formed using the two patterns `Y` and `YX`. André’s hint may help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F$ be the function of the solution.

Let $n$ be the number of characters in the string.

Let $R$ be the maximum number of consecutive 'X' characters.

Assuming that the terms for $n < 0$ are $0$:

$F_{n<0} = 0$

and that the terms for $n = 0$ and $n = 1$ are $1$:

$F_0 = F_1 = 1$

then for a positive integer $R$, the value of any term where $n > 1$ is given by:

$$F_n =\sum_{F_{n-1-R}}^{F_{n-1}}$$

This function can be expressed in the Java programming language as:

```
static int func(int n, int r) {
    if (n < 1) return 0;   // as you required, F(0) = 0
    if (n == 1 || r < 1) return 1;
    int[] a = new int[r + 1];
    a[r] = a[r-1] = 1;     // however, for F(2..) we must have F(0) = 1
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        int x = a[0];
        for (int j = 1; j <= r; j++) {
            x += a[j];
            a[j-1] = a[j];
        }
        a[r] = x;
    }
    return a[r];
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) as Mathjax tutorial.

Comment: I elaborated to the best of my knowledge. Please advise if there's some way I can be more clear.